# Gradle build keeps failing due to MissingBinding on Dagger Hilt migration

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to migrate my project to `Dagger Hilt` and facing an issue with missing binding. I was following the Googles [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-dagger-to-hilt/#0) to achieve this.

This is the place where the build fails:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class ApplicationC implements WhatToCookApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<?>>> is injected at
          dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector(�, injectorFactoriesWithStringKeys)
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<java.lang.Object> is injected at
          dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.androidInjector
      at.bwappsandmore.whattocook.MainActivity is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [at.bwappsandmore.whattocook.WhatToCookApp_HiltComponents.ApplicationC ? at.bwappsandmore.whattocook.di.ActivityModule_InjectMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent]
  It is also requested at:
      dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector(�, injectorFactoriesWithStringKeys)
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
```

These are the relevant parts of the project:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
open class WhatToCookApp : Application() {

    val appComponent: AppComponent by lazy {
        initializeComponent()
    }
    open fun initializeComponent(): AppComponent {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(applicationContext)
    }
}
```

The AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AppModule::class,
        ActivityModule::class,
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class]
)

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<WhatToCookApp> {
    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance appContext: Context): AppComponent
    }
}
```

The AppModule:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideDB(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getDatabase(context)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideDAO(app: AppDatabase): WhatToCookDao {
        return app.whatToCookDao()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAppRepository(dao: WhatToCookDao): AppRepository{
        return AppRepository(dao)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    }
}
```

The ApplicationModulde:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
interface ActivityModule {
    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ViewModelModule::class])
    fun injectMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

The ViewModelModule:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    companion object{
        @Provides
        fun providesSharedViewModel (activity: MainActivity) : SharedViewModel = activity.viewModel
    }
}
```

The ActivityScope:

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityScope
```

I realise that I have to use the `@Provides` annotation for the `AndroidInjector`, but I don't know where and how. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If you want to start using `hilt` you can (or actually "should") remove a lot of what you have in your code samples. You're trying to mix-and-match `dagger.android` with `hilt` and it's not the way to go. As the first step remove everything related to `dagger.android` (`AndroidInjector` and stuff...).

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment - I'll give it a try with all the changes you proposed. Cheers

Comment: @BartekLipinski Bartek, could you please take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476494/issues-with-hilt-on-invoking-a-broadcastreceiver) issue of mine with `Hilt`? I'm really curios to know, what am I missing. Thank you so much. Cheers.